# Get input from textbox populate Autocomplete does not work

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, github

Please How do I get a user and spool into autocomplete from github REST api? I am trying to feed the information from github rest api into an input box and then create an auto complete inputbox, somehow it does not work, it does not feed the information into the inputbox neither does it generate the autocomplete correctly.

Sharing my source code , it looks thus

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Home.css'


const SearchRepo = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    const loadUsers = async()=>{
        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${users}`);
        setUsers(response.data);
    }
    loadUsers();
},[])

const onSuggestHandler = (text)=>{
    setText(text);
    setSuggestions([]);
}

const onChangeHandler = (text) =>{
    //setSeachUser(e.target.value);
    let matches = []
    if(text.length > 0){
        matches = users.filter(user =>{
            const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`,"gi");
            return user.login.match(regex);
        })
    } 
    setSuggestions(matches);
    setText(text);
}


    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" width="100%" height="212px">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" height="55px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                        <font face="Berlin Sans FB" color="#333333">Github Repo Search</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">
                            <table border="0" width="100%" className="SearchTable">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="      Enter github repo ID / username" name="T1" size="88" value={text} onBlur={()=>{setTimeout(()=>{setSuggestions([])},100)}} onChange={e =>onChangeHandler(e.target.value)} className="inputArea" />
                                    {suggestions && suggestions.map((suggestion,i)=>
                                        <div key={i} className="suggestion" onClick={()=>onSuggestHandler(suggestion.login)}>{suggestion.login}</div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div align="center">
                            <table border="0" width="100%" className="reposresultsTable">
                                <div align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                                            <font face="Verdana" size="2" className="labeltxt"><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Repos</h3></font></b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </div>

                                <div align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="23">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                                            <font face="Verdana" size="2">
                                                <a href="https://test-restapi2.herokuapp.com/employees/">
                                                    mmmmmmmm</a></font></b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </div>

                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchRepo;
```

Just need it to get the user and put into the inputbox for Autocomplete

Comment: Sorry it's really hard to understand whay you are asking.

Comment: ok, i have an input box i made into an autocomplete like google autocomplete, you type something and it gives suggestions like google search

Now it should fetch the users from a REST api , in this case, the api is from github, it gets it with axios and populates the suggestions from the input <input /> box

@hellogoodnight, u understand now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your HTTP request calls and make sure to retrieve users and set suggestions properly. At the moment, you're calling the GitHub API users endpoint with your state variable users, which is initialized to '[]':

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // the following function can't work as intended
    const loadUsers = async()=>{
        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${users}`);  // users value is []
        setUsers(response.data);
    }
    loadUsers();
},[])
```

Comment: what must I do in this case pls

Comment: i think I need to make calls to this api instead. https://api.github.com/users